# Visualforce page state is lost when calling a controller method after page is loaded

Tags: apex, visualforce, viewstate

In **classic** after my visualforce page has loaded the controller state is not lost. So if I click a save button the controller variables have values and the logic executes.

In **lightning** after my visualforce page has loaded the controller state is lost. So if I click a save button the variables are null and the logic does not execute.

What should I be looking for?

Comment: can you share some code

Comment: Are you using the same page in lightning that you use in classic?